# Provide large images for "good" (dual core+) phones and smaller, less resolution

Tags: android, image, animation, image-size

I got several images within my app which are animated in various ways.
The problem is that 'weaker' phones, e.g. Samsung Galaxy S1 can't show these animations fluently.
In contrast, animations run very smoothly on the Samsung Galaxy S2 which has an dual core processor.

I have found out, that I can get these animations run fluently when using less-resolution images.
Problem: I don't want to use low-resolution images if I can use high-resolution ones, as these look better.

I could check programatically what's the number of cpus, but that wouldn't be the best style, would it?

It would be cool, I could let android detect this, so I just need to write imageView.setImage(R.drawable.tree); and wheter single core or dual core, the appropriate image is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) might help. Although it's designed for screen density, not CPU power.